# can you shrink db when dbo DoscStreams is almost full?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

I am not an expert in SharePoint server maintenance and i received an notice that one of the database has reached it 93% usage of disk space. i know from research that dbo.DocStreams contains the binary content of documents on your Site Collections within the content database.

Now my suggestions is  for the users to clean up the documents in the doc library or increase the disk space. but db team is against increasing it.

what options do i have? do i shrink the db? would that have any effects on the documents in the site collection?

Comment: Why your DB team is against it? if it is live system it is expected to grow. As Trevor is pointing out only other way would be to remove some content.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have users clean up documents (probably a significant amount) then empty the SharePoint recycle bins for the corresponding sites where the data is deleted. You could then have the DBAs shrink the database (this usually ruins performance; a reindex is generally recommended) to reclaim disk space.